# How can I make a website page like you select the color and the item's color changed like the selected color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, photoshop

I actually did not know the specific name of this situation (if it has), my problem is this;
I want to build a web page like pages at the shopping sites or official car company website.

For example, you want to buy a t-shirt and it has color options when you click the colors the image of the t-shirt is changing like the selected color or in official car company website the cars has a color options and you select the color the website shows that color of a car.

I did something like this but 4 color options and I changed the colors on it photoshop it is working but I have 4 different images and I need to do this like 100 different colors. But I cannot make 100 different images for this is there any way to handle this problem?

I hope, I could explain myself.

Thank you!

Comment: If you dont understand the situation please ask, I need support!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking if there is a way to Photoshop an image programmatically. I tried this out an I think I have a solution.

First you should take your image. Then using photoshop or any other software, make the object that needs its color changed transparent. Then look at the code below and adapt accordingly.

JS:

```
function blue() {
    document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
function red() {
    document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
function green() {
    document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="blue()">Blue</button>
<button onclick="red()">Red</button>
<button onclick="green()">Green</button>

<div id="div" style="z-index: 1; background-color: blue; width:550; height:718;"> //Insert the width and height of the picture
<img src="Picture1.png" style="z-index:2;"/> //Picture1 is the picture with the object
</div>
```

When you click the button 'Red', the background color of the div changes to red and because you made the object's background transparent, the object should appear red.

[View example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awezod?editors=1010#0)